# Can Execution be possible without using testng.xml file and using only pom.xml file in selenium java POM project?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, testng.xml

How to execute Testng and Maven without testng.xml file using only pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it wouldn't be possible to execute *Testng* based *Test Suite* to be executed only through Maven i.e. using only `pom.xml` without using `testng.xml`.

You need to configure *Maven* i.e. `pom.xml` with the desired `testng.xml` file as a mandatory configuration as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I cannot agree. According to the Surefire plugin documentation `As long as they (test classes) are named in accordance with the defaults such as *Test.java they will be run by Surefire as TestNG tests.`. It means that you can run all your test by simply command`mvn test` or specific test `mvn test -Dtest=classTest` without testng.xml and without tag `<suiteXmlFile>` in configuration of surefire plugin.

Comment: @Omeniq Sounds interesting. Can you share the link to the documentation please?

Comment: Here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html.

Comment: @Omeniq Thanks much for the link. Possibly that's why specifically mentioned **_Testng based Test Suite_** (not **tests**).